# How to calaculate HMAC-SHA3 in Android using Crypto.js?

Tags: java, android, hmac, sha-3

I am using Android Studio 1.22 and JRE 1.8 with 64 bit JVM. How to import Crypto,js to Android?

I want to calculate 6 digit OTP from HMAC output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this from Google code : 
[Google Authenticator](https://code.google.com/p/vellum/wiki/GoogleAuthenticator)

You can find step-by-step JAVA sample code in there.

Cheers.

Comment: Google Authenticator uses HMAC-SHA1. But I want HMAC-SHA3. Where will I get code for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find implementation in java here :

https://github.com/romus/sha/blob/master/sha3/src/com/theromus/example/Main.java